# Netty HTTPRequest doesn't captured posted JSOn

Tags: json, post, netty

I am attempting to build a REST service using Netty on the backend. I need to be able to post raw JSON to the service outside of any key/value parameters. Content-type=applicaiton/json not form multi-part.

I am able to get the initial part of the service to receive the request, but when I cast the MessageEvent content to HTTPRequest, it no longer has any posed data associated with it. That leaves me with no ability to get the JSON data back.

In order to access the posted JSON, do I need to use a different process for extracting the data from the MessageEvent?

Here is the snippet in question.

```
 @Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The message was received");
    HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
    if (request.getMethod() != POST) {
        sendError(ctx, METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return;
    }


    // Validate that we have the correct URI and if so, then parse the incoming data.

    final String path = sanitizeUri(request.getUri());
    decoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(request);
    System.out.println("We have the decoder for the request");
    List<InterfaceHttpData> datas = decoder.getBodyHttpDatas();
    for (InterfaceHttpData data : datas){
     System.out.println(data.toString());
    }
```

What am I missing that it causing this? Do I need to use the ChunkedWrite portion? I am a noob to Netty so forgive me if this is basic. I found lots of other questions about posting raw JSON to other URL's from inside Netty, but nothing about receiving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only used `HttpPostRequestDecoder` to read `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or mime data.

Try just reading the data directly form the request as per the [snoop](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java) example.

```
ChannelBuffer content = request.getContent();
if (content.readable()) {
    String json = content.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: Working [link](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java) to the snoop example